# Toolchains built from MinGW and Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mingw

Scenario:
Lets say i got 2 PC running windows. On PC1, i installed MinGW and use the MinGW GNU toolchain (call this, M0) to build a GNU toolchain (lets call this toolchain, M1). Both M0 and M1 toolchains are native windows apps.

On PC2, i installed Cygwin and use the Cygwin GNU toolchain (call this, C0) to build a GNU toolchain (lets call this toolchain, C1). Both C0 and C1 are also native windows apps, BUT both have a dependency on the cygwin dlls, i.e. they cannot run without these dlls.

If i use C1 toolchain to build other native windows apps, do these window apps also have dependency on the cygwin dlls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not supplying enough information in your question to give an answer. If you build a Cygwin toolchain, then yes, any apps built using that will require Cygwin1.dll.

But it sounds like you might be trying to create some sort of cross compiled toolchain to build native windows apps from Cygwin. If that's the case, then, if you do it correctly, then no, the native windows apps built from your cross-compiler will not require cygwin1.dll.

This would be a very painful way to do it, though. Cygwin includes a toolchain that can be used to build native apps that don't depend on cygwin1.dll.

This is covered in the [FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin) under "How do I compile a Win32 executable that doesn't use Cygwin?"